# Total number of Questions and Grads/Points in Exam class

Tags: exam

I am using the `exam` template and wonder how to count the total number of questions and the total number of marks to provide the totals on a cover sheet (before declaring them)?

Here is what I have. I am sure it is easy, but was not able to find an example or the right commands in the documentation...

Can anybody help?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document} 

% some hearder and student info here, excluded for simplicity

% instructions
\textbf{Instructions:}

% how to count questions and marks to give the totals on a cover sheet?
This exam contains XXX questions, \numpages pages (including the cover) for the total of XXX marks.

\begin{questions}
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[10] Differentiate $f(x)=x^2$ with respect to $x$.
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[10] Differentiate $f(x)=x^3$ with respect to $x$.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try : `This exam contains \numquestions{} questions, \numpages{} pages (including the cover) for the total of \numpoints{}  marks.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 4.7 of the `exam` document reveals that there are some commands as

`\numquestions`, `\numpages`, `\numpoints` amongst others which just print the value of the relevant counter at the end of the document. `exam` uses a `totcounter` - like approach.

Note: `\numquestions questions` will print `2questions`, i.e. either use `\numquestions{} questions` (as proposed by touhami) or `\numquestions\ questions` to provide the necessary explicit space.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document} 

% some hearder and student info here, excluded for simplicity

% instructions
\textbf{Instructions:}

% how to count questions and marks to give the totals on a cover sheet?
This exam contains \numquestions\ questions, \numpages\ pages (including the cover) for the total of \numpoints\ marks.

\begin{questions}
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[10] Differentiate $f(x)=x^2$ with respect to $x$.
% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[10] Differentiate $f(x)=x^3$ with respect to $x$.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I think it is worth pointing out that, at least in my experimentation, `\addpoints` is only needed once, and *must* be before the first question you want to add the points of.  Is that correct?

Comment: @kcrisman: This depends on the setup, I would say

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you mean the version of the package, or ... ?